# Writing a low-level language from hardware

Tags: compiler-construction, low-level, hardware

I am interested in finding out how to compile/create a very simple language (i.e. brainfuck) without the help of high-level functions like unix system calls. I would like to write a compiler for the language in some CPU-dependent low-level assembly such that I can provide source code in the simple language and end up with a binary. Not sure if this is clear or not, but the basic question is how to convert source to binary without the help of anything that is not already present in the hardware.

Edit: A more concise problem statement...

**GIVEN:**

-Hardware (motherboard/CPU, etc.)

**NOT GIVEN:**

-UNIX/DOS

-C/FORTRAN/any other languages

How would I go about implementing a simple language like brainfuck?

I am aware that there are much more practical ways of compiling, but I am interested in this for educational purposes.

Sorry if this question is redundant or obvious - I am not a computer scientist so perhaps I just don't know the proper vocabulary to find a solution to the problem online. If anyone can provide a link or text on the subject it would be appreciated.

Comment: A bit more practical thing to do would be to implement Forth from scratch on a bare metal. And then you'll be able to use it for bootstrapping a more complex system on top of it.

Comment: Ok... this sounds like what I am interested in. I assume by "bare metal" you mean hardware only? Is there a good tutorial for doing this? Forth is fine... as I said I am only interested for educational purposes so if I understand how to do it with Forth I will be happy.

Comment: Yes, there are many tutorials, like this one: http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/2452 or this: http://hbrobotics.org/wiki/index.php?title=Forth_for_Robotics_and_Programming_at_the_Bare_Metal

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the description on wikipedia this is not a difficult task.  I would still probably start in some language you know and perhaps like, perhaps not.  C is a good choice.  File I/O is a small or huge project depending on the platform, etc.  Worry about that later, compile in the "source" for the language.  for each character in that source, perform the task

```
> ++ptr;
< --ptr;
+ ++*ptr;
etc
```

then translate that to assembly.  you only need one register to hold ptr, a few lines of asm to initialize the array/ram and set the register/ptr to the beginning.  Another register to walk through the source code.  you are only looking for 8 characters, you could if-then-else your way through those unless there is a bit pattern thing that makes them easier to deal with.  if you want you could make a 256byte look up table and use that either for the address to the handler for that instruction or to convert them into a integer from 0-7, and use that in a jump table, whatever.

Well that is a parser, not necessarily a compiler.  I would write the compiler in C or some high level language, it takes in an array of bytes which is the program, for each instruction you output the asm source code that implements that instruction, you get a less than byte on input, output (using ARM asm)

```
add r0,#1
```

a minus sign

```
ldr r1,[r0]
sub r1,#1
str r1,[r0]
```

r0 being the ptr register and r1 just helping out.

If you are really opposed to using calls like printf, then make the output of this code an array of bytes which are the ascii for the asm source out put each character a, d, d, space, r, 0, comma, #, 1, cr, lf  and so on.  Fairly easy to implement in asm as well as some high level language.  If you want to go straight to binary then simply output machine code, even easier.

Getting the source string into this compiler and the output into some file that can be then later executed is likely going to take system calls.  You can avoid the output being a file if you are running on the same platform and can do self-modifying code in the sense that you build up the machine code at some address, and then when finished parsing you jump to that address to execute.

it took many times longer to write this answer than it would have been to implement the solution in C or asm. What is the exact difficulty you are having?

Comment: ahh, actually the input/output that the program generates, dot(.) and comma(,) are problematic as you have to get into what could be a significant amount of code.  Have your output be an array in ram somewhere, or if embedded use a uart and spit the bytes out the uart, whcih is usually minimal amounts of code, a few lines for the uart putchar function.  input on a uart is also minimal.

Comment: Thanks for the input... it sounds as if my problem has more to do with file I/O. I know how to write a compiler in C/assembly, but I am curious as to how one would implement a language in the absence of such conveniences. Basically how can you implement a language if all you are given is hardware (presumably including the BIOS)? I hope my edit has clarified the question.

Comment: @AJMedford: Well, you write your I/O and file system drivers too, if that's what you lack.

Answer (score 1):

You can compile brainfuck source code into DOS .COM apps quite easily (you'll also need NASM or some extra code to emit instruction opcodes and calculate jumps). Below is a slightly modified bf interpreter, turned into a compiler of sorts:

```
// file: bfcompil.c

#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_CODE_SIZE 30000

char code[MAX_CODE_SIZE];
char* pc = &code[0];
char* pcEnd = &code[0];

#define MAX_DATA_SIZE 30000

char data[MAX_DATA_SIZE] = { 0 };
char* pd = &data[0];

// Structures for quick bracket matching
unsigned brStack[MAX_CODE_SIZE];
unsigned brSptr = 0;
unsigned brMatch[MAX_CODE_SIZE];

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  FILE* f = NULL;
  int ch;

  if (argc != 2)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "usage:\n  bfcompil <brainfuck-source-code-file>\n"
                    "bfcompil will output NASM-compilable source code for"
                    "a DOS program\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  if ((f = fopen(argv[1], "rb")) == NULL)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "can't open file \"%s\" for reading\n", argv[1]);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  while ((ch = getc(f)) != EOF)
  {
    if (strchr(" \t\r\n", ch) != NULL) // skip white space
    {
      continue;
    }
    else if (strchr("><+-.,[]", ch) != NULL) // store valid commands
    {
      if (pcEnd >= &code[sizeof(code)])
      {
        fprintf(stderr, "too many commands in file \"%s\", expected at most "
                        "%u commands\n", argv[1], (unsigned)sizeof(code));
        fclose(f);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
      }

      if (ch == '[')
      {
        brStack[brSptr++] = (unsigned)(pcEnd - &code[0]);
      }
      else if (ch == ']')
      {
        if (brSptr == 0)
        {
          fprintf(stderr, "unmatched ']' in file \"%s\"\n", argv[1]);
          fclose(f);
          return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        brSptr--;
        brMatch[brStack[brSptr]] = (unsigned)(pcEnd - &code[0]);
        brMatch[pcEnd - &code[0]] = brStack[brSptr];
      }

      *pcEnd++ = ch;
    }
    else // fail on invalid commands
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "unexpected character '%c' in file \"%s\", valid command "
                      "set is: \"><+-.,[]\"\n", ch, argv[1]);
      fclose(f);
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
  }

  fclose(f);

  if (brSptr != 0)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "unmatched '[' in file \"%s\"\n", argv[1]);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  if (pcEnd == &code[0])
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "no commands found in file \"%s\"\n", argv[1]);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  printf("; how to compile: nasm -f bin <input file with this code.asm> -o "
         "<output executable.com>\n\n"
         "org 0x100\n"
         "bits 16\n\n"
         "    mov     bx, data\n"
         "    mov     di, bx\n"
         "    mov     cx, 30000\n"
         "    xor     al, al\n"
         "    cld\n"
         "    rep     stosb\n\n"
         "    jmp     code\n\n"
         "print:\n"
         "    mov     ah, 2\n"
         "    cmp     byte [bx], 10\n"
         "    jne     lprint1\n"
         "    mov     dl, 13\n"
         "    int     0x21\n"
         "lprint1:\n"
         "    mov     dl, [bx]\n"
         "    int     0x21\n"
         "    ret\n\n"
#if 01
         // buffered input
         "input:\n"
         "    cmp     byte [kbdbuf+1], 0\n"
         "    jne     linput1\n"
         "    mov     ah, 0xa\n"
         "    mov     dx, kbdbuf\n"
         "    int     0x21\n"
         "    inc     byte [kbdbuf+1]\n"
         "linput1:\n"
         "    mov     al, [kbdbuf+2]\n"
         "    cmp     al, 13\n"
         "    jne     linput4\n"
         "    mov     al, 10\n"
         "linput4:\n"
         "    mov     [bx], al\n"
         "    mov     si, kbdbuf+3\n"
         "    mov     di, kbdbuf+2\n"
         "    xor     cx, cx\n"
         "    dec     byte [kbdbuf+1]\n"
         "    mov     cl, [kbdbuf+1]\n"
         "    jz      linput3\n"
         "linput2:\n"
         "    lodsb\n"
         "    stosb\n"
         "    loop    linput2\n"
         "linput3:\n"
         "    ret\n\n"
#else
         // unbuffered input
         "input:\n"
         "    mov     ah, 1\n"
         "    int     0x21\n"
         "    cmp     al, 13\n"
         "    jne     linput\n"
         "    mov     al, 10\n"
         "linput:\n"
         "    mov     [bx], al\n"
         "    ret\n\n"
#endif
         "code:\n\n");

  for (pc = &code[0]; pc < pcEnd; pc++)
  {
    switch (*pc)
    {
    case '>':
      printf("    inc     bx\n");
      break;
    case '<':
      printf("    dec     bx\n");
      break;
    case '+':
      printf("    inc     byte [bx]\n");
      break;
    case '-':
      printf("    dec     byte [bx]\n");
      break;
    case '.':
      printf("    call    print\n");
      break;
    case ',':
      printf("    call    input\n");
      break;
    case '[':
      printf("label%u:\n", (unsigned)(pc - &code[0]));
      printf("    cmp     byte [bx], 0\n");
      printf("    je      label%u\n", (unsigned)brMatch[pc - &code[0]]);
      break;
    case ']':
      printf("    jmp     label%u\n", brMatch[pc - &code[0]]);
      printf("label%u:\n", (unsigned)(pc - &code[0]));
      break;
    }
  }

  printf("\n    ret\n\n");
  printf("kbdbuf:\n"
         "    db      254\n"
         "    db      0\n"
         "    times   256 db 0\n\n");
  printf("data:\n");

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If you feed it the hello world program:

```
++++++++++[>+++++++>++++++++++>+++>+<<<<-]>++.>+.+++++++..+++.>++.<<+++++++++++++++.>.+++.------.--------.>+.>.
```

It'll produce compilable assembly code:

```
; how to compile: nasm -f bin <input file with this code.asm> -o <output executable.com>

org 0x100
bits 16

    mov     bx, data
    mov     di, bx
    mov     cx, 30000
    xor     al, al
    cld
    rep     stosb

    jmp     code

print:
    mov     ah, 2
    cmp     byte [bx], 10
    jne     lprint1
    mov     dl, 13
    int     0x21
lprint1:
    mov     dl, [bx]
    int     0x21
    ret

input:
    cmp     byte [kbdbuf+1], 0
    jne     linput1
    mov     ah, 0xa
    mov     dx, kbdbuf
    int     0x21
    inc     byte [kbdbuf+1]
linput1:
    mov     al, [kbdbuf+2]
    cmp     al, 13
    jne     linput4
    mov     al, 10
linput4:
    mov     [bx], al
    mov     si, kbdbuf+3
    mov     di, kbdbuf+2
    xor     cx, cx
    dec     byte [kbdbuf+1]
    mov     cl, [kbdbuf+1]
    jz      linput3
linput2:
    lodsb
    stosb
    loop    linput2
linput3:
    ret

code:

    inc     byte [bx]
    inc     byte [bx]
    inc     byte [bx]
    inc     byte [bx]
    inc     byte [bx]
    inc     byte [bx]
    inc     byte [bx]
    inc     byte [bx]
    inc     byte [bx]
    inc     byte [bx]
label10:
    cmp     byte [bx], 0
    je      label41
    inc     bx
    inc     byte [bx]
    inc     byte [bx]
    inc     byte [bx]
    inc     byte [bx]
    inc     byte [bx]
    inc     byte [bx]
    inc     byte [bx]
    inc     bx
    inc     byte [bx]
    inc     byte [bx]
    inc     byte [bx]
    inc     byte [bx]
    inc     byte [bx]
    inc     byte [bx]
    inc     byte [bx]
    inc     byte [bx]
    inc     byte [bx]
    inc     byte [bx]
    inc     bx
    inc     byte [bx]
    inc     byte [bx]
    inc     byte [bx]
    inc     bx
    inc     byte [bx]
    dec     bx
    dec     bx
    dec     bx
    dec     bx
    dec     byte [bx]
    jmp     label10
label41:
    inc     bx
    inc     byte [bx]
    inc     byte [bx]
    call    print
    inc     bx
    inc     byte [bx]
    call    print
    inc     byte [bx]
    inc     byte [bx]
    inc     byte [bx]
    inc     byte [bx]
    inc     byte [bx]
    inc     byte [bx]
    inc     byte [bx]
    call    print
    call    print
    inc     byte [bx]
    inc     byte [bx]
    inc     byte [bx]
    call    print
    inc     bx
    inc     byte [bx]
    inc     byte [bx]
    call    print
    dec     bx
    dec     bx
    inc     byte [bx]
    inc     byte [bx]
    inc     byte [bx]
    inc     byte [bx]
    inc     byte [bx]
    inc     byte [bx]
    inc     byte [bx]
    inc     byte [bx]
    inc     byte [bx]
    inc     byte [bx]
    inc     byte [bx]
    inc     byte [bx]
    inc     byte [bx]
    inc     byte [bx]
    inc     byte [bx]
    call    print
    inc     bx
    call    print
    inc     byte [bx]
    inc     byte [bx]
    inc     byte [bx]
    call    print
    dec     byte [bx]
    dec     byte [bx]
    dec     byte [bx]
    dec     byte [bx]
    dec     byte [bx]
    dec     byte [bx]
    call    print
    dec     byte [bx]
    dec     byte [bx]
    dec     byte [bx]
    dec     byte [bx]
    dec     byte [bx]
    dec     byte [bx]
    dec     byte [bx]
    dec     byte [bx]
    call    print
    inc     bx
    inc     byte [bx]
    call    print
    inc     bx
    call    print

    ret

kbdbuf:
    db      254
    db      0
    times   256 db 0

data:
```

If you compile it, you'll be able to run it in DOS, Windows 9x/XP (probably 32-bit Vista/7) and in DosBox.

The output, unsurprisingly, is:

```
Hello World!
```

**UPDATE**: The DOS-based input and output routines in the above code can be replaced by direct accesses to the screen buffer and keyboard ports. The keyboard code will also need to handle keyboard interrupts. It's not very hard to do on the x86 PC. You really can implement a compiler for a language to run on bare hardware without OS.

You should also take a look at `Forth` as that's exactly the kind of language for the given environment. And it's easy to implement. Much easier than C. Harder than brainfuck, somewhat comparable with assembly.

**UPDATE 2**: Here's a small (~1KB in size) brainfuck interpreter that's not using any DOS or BIOS functionality:

```
; file: bfint.asm
; compile: nasm.exe -f bin bfint.asm -o bfint.com
; run in: DOS, DosBox or equivalent

bits 16
org 0x100

section .text

SCREEN_WIDTH   equ 80
SCREEN_HEIGHT  equ 25
SCAN_BUF_SIZE  equ 256

MAX_CODE_SIZE  equ 20000
MAX_DATA_SIZE  equ 30000

    cld

    ; set new keyboard (IRQ1) ISR
    push    byte 0
    pop     es
    cli                         ; update ISR address w/ ints disabled
    mov     word [es:9*4], Irq1Isr
    mov     [es:9*4+2], cs
    sti

    push    cs
    pop     es

Restart:

    call    ClearScreen
    mov     si, MsgHello
    call    PrintStr

    mov     word [CodeSize], 0
    mov     byte [EnterCount], 0

WaitForKey:
    call    GetKey

    ; Escape erases code
    cmp     ah, 1      ; Escape
    je      Restart

    ; Non-characters are ignored
    cmp     al, 0      ; non-character key
    je      WaitForKey

    ; Enter is "printed" but not stored, use for formatting
    cmp     al, 10     ; Enter
    je      KeyEnter
    mov     byte [EnterCount], 0

    ; Backspace deletes last character
    cmp     al, 8      ; Backspace
    je      KeyBackspace

    ; Space is printed but not stored, use for formatting
    cmp     al, " "    ; Space
    je      PrintOnly

    ; 0 runs a test program
    cmp     al, "0"
    je      TestProgram

    ; Other chracters are stored as code
    mov     bx, [CodeSize]
    cmp     bx, MAX_CODE_SIZE
    jae     ErrCodeTooBig
    mov     [Code + bx], al
    inc     word [CodeSize]
PrintOnly:
    call    PrintChar
    jmp     WaitForKey

ErrCodeTooBig:
    mov     si, MsgCodeTooBig
    call    PrintStr
    mov     word [CodeSize], 0
    jmp     WaitForKey

KeyEnter:
    call    PrintChar
    inc     byte [EnterCount]
    cmp     byte [EnterCount], 1
    je      WaitForKey
    mov     byte [EnterCount], 0
    call    Execute
    jmp     WaitForKey

KeyBackspace:
    call    PrintChar
    cmp     word [CodeSize], 0
    je      WaitForKey
    dec     word [CodeSize]
    jmp     WaitForKey

TestProgram:
    mov     si, TestCode
    mov     di, Code
    mov     cx, TestCodeEnd - TestCode
    mov     [CodeSize], cx
    rep     movsb
    call    Execute
    jmp     WaitForKey

Execute:
    mov     si, Code ; code start
    xor     bp, bp ; instruction index

    mov     di, Data ; data start
    mov     cx, MAX_DATA_SIZE
    xor     al, al
    rep     stosb
    sub     di, MAX_DATA_SIZE
    xor     bx, bx ; data index

ExecuteLoop:
    cmp     bp, [CodeSize]
    jae     ExecuteDone

    mov     al, [bp+si]
    cmp     al, ">"
    je      IncPtr
    cmp     al, "<"
    je      DecPtr
    cmp     al, "+"
    je      IncData
    cmp     al, "-"
    je      DecData
    cmp     al, "."
    je      PrintData
    cmp     al, ","
    je      InputData
    cmp     al, "["
    je      While
    cmp     al, "]"
    je      EndWhile

    mov     si, MsgInvalidChar
    call    PrintStr
    call    PrintChar
    mov     al, 10
    call    PrintChar
    jmp     ExecuteDone

IncPtr:
    inc     bx
    jmp     ExecuteContinue

DecPtr:
    dec     bx
    jmp     ExecuteContinue

IncData:
    inc     byte [bx+di]
    jmp     ExecuteContinue

DecData:
    dec     byte [bx+di]
    jmp     ExecuteContinue

PrintData:
    mov     al, [bx+di]
    call    PrintChar
    jmp     ExecuteContinue

InputData:
    call    GetKey
    or      al, al
    jz      InputData
    mov     [bx+di], al
    jmp     ExecuteContinue

While:
    cmp     byte [bx+di], 0
    jne     ExecuteContinue
    mov     ax, 1
    mov     dx, "[]"
    call    FindMatchingBracket
ExecuteContinue:
    inc     bp
    jmp     ExecuteLoop

EndWhile:
    mov     ax, -1
    mov     dx, "]["
    call    FindMatchingBracket
    jmp     ExecuteLoop

ExecuteDone:
    mov     word [CodeSize], 0
    mov     si, MsgCompleted
    jmp     PrintStr

FindMatchingBracket:
    xor     cx, cx
FindMatchingBracket1:
    cmp     byte [bp+si], dl
    jne     FindMatchingBracket2
    inc     cx
    jmp     FindMatchingBracket3
FindMatchingBracket2:
    cmp     byte [bp+si], dh
    jne     FindMatchingBracket3
    dec     cx
    jnz     FindMatchingBracket3
    ret
FindMatchingBracket3:
    add     bp, ax
    jmp     FindMatchingBracket1

; Inputs:
; AL = ASCII character code
PrintChar:
    ; assuming it's a color text mode (not monochrome or graphics)
    pusha
    push    es

    push    word 0xb800
    pop     es
    mov     bx, [CursorPos]

    cmp     al, 8
    je      PrintCharBackSpace

    cmp     al, 10
    je      PrintCharBackLF

    cmp     al, 13
    je      PrintCharBackCR

    mov     [es:bx], al
    call    AdvanceCursorPosition

    jmp     PrintCharDone

PrintCharBackSpace:
    ; move the cursor back and erase the last character
    or      bx, bx
    jz      PrintCharDone
    dec     bx
    dec     bx
    mov     word [es:bx], 0x0720
    jmp     PrintCharSetCursorPos

PrintCharBackLF:
    ; move the cursor to the beginning of the next line - '\n' behavior
    add     bx, SCREEN_WIDTH * 2
    cmp     bx, SCREEN_WIDTH * SCREEN_HEIGHT * 2
    jc      PrintCharBackCR
    sub     bx, SCREEN_WIDTH * 2
    call    ScrollUp

PrintCharBackCR:
    ; move the cursor to the beginning of the current line - '\r' behavior
    mov     ax, SCREEN_WIDTH * 2
    xchg    ax, bx
    xor     dx, dx
    div     bx
    mul     bx
    mov     bx, ax

PrintCharSetCursorPos:
    mov     [CursorPos], bx
    shr     bx, 1
    call    SetCursorPosition

PrintCharDone:
PopEsAllRet:
    pop     es
    popa
    ret

ClearScreen:
    ; assuming it's a color text mode (not monochrome or graphics)
    pusha
    push    es

    push    word 0xb800
    pop     es
    xor     di, di
    mov     cx, SCREEN_WIDTH * SCREEN_HEIGHT
    mov     ax, 0x0720 ; character = space, color = lightgray on black
    rep     stosw

    xor     bx, bx
    mov     [CursorPos], bx
    call    SetCursorPosition

    jmp     PopEsAllRet

ScrollUp:
    ; assuming it's a color text mode (not monochrome or graphics)
    pusha
    push    es
    push    ds

    push    word 0xb800
    pop     es
    push    es
    pop     ds
    mov     si, SCREEN_WIDTH * 2
    xor     di, di
    mov     cx, SCREEN_WIDTH * (SCREEN_HEIGHT - 1)
    rep     movsw

    mov     cx, SCREEN_WIDTH
    mov     ax, 0x0720 ; character = space, color = lightgray on black
    rep     stosw

    pop     ds
    jmp     PopEsAllRet

; Inputs:
; DS:SI = address of NUL-terminated ASCII string
PrintStr:
    pusha
PrintStr1:
    lodsb
    or      al, al
    jz      PrintStrDone
    call    PrintChar
    jmp     PrintStr1
PrintStrDone:
    popa
    ret

; Inputs:
; BX = Y * SCREEN_WIDTH + X
SetCursorPosition:
    ; assuming it's a color text mode (not monochrome or graphics)
    pusha

%if 0
    mov     dx, 0x3d4
    mov     al, 0x0f
    out     dx, al
    inc     dx
    mov     al, bl
    out     dx, al

    dec     dx
    mov     al, 0x0e
    out     dx, al
    inc     dx
    mov     al, bh
    out     dx, al
%else
    mov     dx, 0x3d4
    mov     al, 0x0f
    mov     ah, bl
    out     dx, ax

    dec     al
    mov     ah, bh
    out     dx, ax
%endif

    popa
    ret

AdvanceCursorPosition:
    ; assuming it's a color text mode (not monochrome or graphics)
    pusha

    mov     ax, [CursorPos]
    inc     ax
    inc     ax
    cmp     ax, SCREEN_WIDTH * SCREEN_HEIGHT * 2
    jc      AdvanceCursorPosition1

    sub     ax, SCREEN_WIDTH * 2
    call    ScrollUp

AdvanceCursorPosition1:
    mov     [CursorPos], ax
    shr     ax, 1
    xchg    ax, bx
    call    SetCursorPosition

    popa
    ret

; Outputs:
; AH = scan code
; AL = character
GetKey:
    push    bx
    push    si

GetKeyRepeat:
    mov     ax, [ScanWriteIdx]
    mov     si, [ScanReadIdx]
    sub     ax, si
    jz      GetKeyRepeat
    mov     bx, si
    mov     ax, [ScanBuf + bx + si]
    inc     si
    and     si, SCAN_BUF_SIZE - 1
    mov     [ScanReadIdx], si

    pop     si
    pop     bx
    ret

Irq1Isr:
    pusha
    push    ds

    push    cs
    pop     ds

    ; read keyboard scan code
    in      al, 0x60

    cmp     al, 0x2a ; Left Shift down
    jne     Irq1Isr1
    or      byte [Shift], 1
Irq1Isr1:
    cmp     al, 0x36 ; Right Shift down
    jne     Irq1Isr2
    or      byte [Shift], 2
Irq1Isr2:
    cmp     al, 0xaa ; Left Shift up
    jne     Irq1Isr3
    and     byte [Shift], ~1
Irq1Isr3:
    cmp     al, 0xb6 ; Right Shift up
    jne     Irq1Isr4
    and     byte [Shift], ~2
Irq1Isr4:

    test    al, 0x80
    jnz     Irq1IsrEois ; key released

    mov     ah, al
    cmp     al, 58
    jc      Irq1Isr5
    xor     al, al   ; don't translate non-character keys
    jmp     Irq1Isr7
Irq1Isr5:
    mov     bx, ScanToChar
    cmp     byte [Shift], 0
    je      Irq1Isr6
    add     bx, ScanToCharShift - ScanToChar
Irq1Isr6:
    xlatb

Irq1Isr7:
    mov     bx, [ScanWriteIdx]
    mov     di, bx
    mov     [ScanBuf + bx + di], ax
    inc     bx
    and     bx, SCAN_BUF_SIZE - 1
    mov     [ScanWriteIdx], bx

Irq1IsrEois:
%if 0
    ; send EOI to XT keyboard
    in      al, 0x61
    mov     ah, al
    or      al, 0x80
    out     0x61, al
    mov     al, ah
    out     0x61, al
%endif

    ; send EOI to master PIC
    mov     al, 0x20
    out     0x20, al

    pop     ds
    popa
    iret

ScanToChar:
    db      0 ; unused
    db      0 ; Escape
    db      "1234567890-="
    db      8 ; Backspace
    db      9 ; Tab
    db      "qwertyuiop[]"
    db      10 ; Enter
    db      0 ; Ctrl
    db      "asdfghjkl;'`"
    db      0 ; Left Shift
    db      "\zxcvbnm,./"
    db      0 ; Right Shift
    db      0 ; Print Screen
    db      0 ; Alt
    db      " " ; Space
ScanToCharShift:
    db      0 ; unused
    db      0 ; Escape
    db      "!@#$%^&*()_+"
    db      8 ; Backspace
    db      9 ; Tab
    db      "QWERTYUIOP{}"
    db      10 ; Enter
    db      0 ; Ctrl
    db      'ASDFGHJKL:"~'
    db      0 ; Left Shift
    db      "|ZXCVBNM<>?"
    db      0 ; Right Shift
    db      0 ; Print Screen
    db      0 ; Alt
    db      " " ; Space

MsgHello:
    db      "Brainfuck Interpreter", 10, 10
    db      "Press 0 to run test code OR", 10
    db      "Type your code.", 10
    db      "Use Esc to erase it all or Backspace to delete last character.", 10
    db      "Press Enter twice to run it.", 10, 10, 0

MsgCodeTooBig:
    db      10, "Code's too big", 10, 0

MsgCompleted:
    db      10, "Code's completed", 10, 0

MsgInvalidChar:
    db      10, "Invalid character: ", 0

Shift           db      0

CursorPos       dw      0

ScanReadIdx     dw      0
ScanWriteIdx    dw      0

EnterCount      db      0

CodeSize        dw      0

TestCode:
    ; Hello World!
    db "++++++++++[>+++++++>++++++++++>+++>+<<<<-]>++.>+.+++++++..+++.>++.<<+++++++++++++++.>.+++.------.--------.>+.>."
    ; Squares of 0 through 100
;    db "++++[>+++++<-]>[<+++++>-]+<+[>[>+>+<<-]++>>[<<+>>-]>>>[-]++>[-]+>>>+[[-]++++++>>>]<<<[[<++++++++<++>>-]+<.<[>----<-]<]<<[>>>>>[>>>[-]+++++++++<[>-<-]+++++++++>[-[<->-]+[<<<]]<[>+<-]>]<<-]<<-]"
    ; ROT13
;    db "+[,+[-[>+>+<<-]>[<+>-]+>>++++++++[<-------->-]<-[<[-]>>>+[<+<+>>-]<[>+<-]<[<++>>>+[<+<->>-]<[>+<-]]>[<]<]>>[-]<<<[[-]<[>>+>+<<<-]>>[<<+>>-]>>++++++++[<-------->-]<->>++++[<++++++++>-]<-<[>>>+<<[>+>[-]<<-]>[<+>-]>[<<<<<+>>>>++++[<++++++++>-]>-]<<-<-]>[<<<<[-]>>>>[<<<<->>>>-]]<<++++[<<++++++++>>-]<<-[>>+>+<<<-]>>[<<+>>-]+>>+++++[<----->-]<-[<[-]>>>+[<+<->>-]<[>+<-]<[<++>>>+[<+<+>>-]<[>+<-]]>[<]<]>>[-]<<<[[-]<<[>>+>+<<<-]>>[<<+>>-]+>------------[<[-]>>>+[<+<->>-]<[>+<-]<[<++>>>+[<+<+>>-]<[>+<-]]>[<]<]>>[-]<<<<<------------->>[[-]+++++[<<+++++>>-]<<+>>]<[>++++[<<++++++++>>-]<-]>]<[-]++++++++[<++++++++>-]<+>]<.[-]+>>+<]>[[-]<]<]"
TestCodeEnd:

section .bss

ScanBuf:
    resw SCAN_BUF_SIZE

Code:
    resb MAX_CODE_SIZE

Data:
    resb MAX_DATA_SIZE
```

If you want to take DOS (as the hosting environment) and NASM out of the picture, you're welcome to encode the above assembly code by hand, make a bootable floppy out of it and boot it.

Comment: you are making system calls, do this without system calls.  In some cases video and keyboard are pretty basic (hundreds to thousands of lines of high level code), but file systems and controlling the hard disk without system calls (the int instruction) are not so trivial.  Even after the edit the poster needs to clarify the question, perhaps with some examples of what is acceptable and what isnt.

Comment: he clearly stated in some cpu dependent low level assembly.  That is not a compiler compiling itself in the same language.  I want the definition of high level system calls, I consider that to be vague and easy to debate the definition in this context.  If an int21 call is okay then so is a call to putchar and just link the asm or C or whatever with a library.  the definition determines if this is a 5 minute programming task or the rest of your life task or somewhere in the middle.

Comment: @dwelch: Hopefully the added interpreter satisfies the requirements.

Comment: @dwelch: You are correct that a self compiling language is not what I am looking for. By high level system calls I mean anything that requires another language/operating system to already exist on the machine. If it exists in the BIOS or some other software system that is flashed to the motherboard then it is okay. I am assuming that it will require going through the BIOS and have ordered a book on BIOS which I hope will help (PC Interrupts by Brown)

Comment: @AJMedford: Is there any problem with the last code I posted? It's not using any BIOS/DOS interrupt service routines, it does all I/O directly with the hardware.

Answer (score 0):

The canonical compiler-learning book is the Dragon Book, http://dragonbook.stanford.edu/  .

However, it really is pointed at more... SOPHISTICATED languages. You might not want to talk about context-free parsing and the like (although I *do* recommend that book, it's double-plus-hard but AWESOME.)

With that in mind, you might want to start by finding an interpreter or compiler for a really simple language-- maybe Brainfuck itself, maybe something a little more usable like a Scheme implementation. Read, analyze, learn what it does. Implement whichever lower-level library functions that compiler uses, adjust its code generator to output whatever brand of machine code you want to target, and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I have a similar project on my mind too. What you want is to write a compiler that runs on bare hardware (without any operating systems). 
A compiler is just a program like every other program except that it will be running on bare hardware as in your case.

You might consider using a bootloader for your compiler (a bootloader is not an operating system). The bootloader normally loads an operating system from the disk into memory for execution only this time it loads your compiler rather than an operating system.

There are many free and open-source bootloaders out there (google for them). Choose one that suits your needs or if you're as curious/inquisitive as I am, you might even write your own.

Choosing a bootloader (or writing one) requires that you know how your target system boots - its either through BIOS (old) or UEFI (new. It is the replacement for BIOS). As your programming language matures, you could write your very own bootloader in your new programming language.

Hope this helps